# how to: installing django on heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

I'm absolutely "brand new" to Paas and django/python.

I would install django on heroku.
Before, I need to install on it Python. But I'm unable to do that. I looked a while for doc about it, but unfortunately I'm not able.

I've created a heroku account. I log in and the try to follow the guide.

please, help me. give me some starting point...

TIA

Renato

Answer (score 1):

## Setting up your project

You'll need to add a couple of files to the root of your project:

The first file, named `requirements.txt`, should contain the dependencies for your project (this is not really Heroku specific). At the minimum, this should include:

```
Django
```

Then, you'll need to add a file named `Profile` (this is more Heroku-specific) that tells Heroku how you run your project:

```
web: gunicorn YOUR_PROJECT_NAME.wsgi:application
```

`YOUR_PROJECT_NAME` should be whatever argument you gave `manage.py startproject`. This should also be the name of the folder that contains your `wsgi.py` file (`settings.py` will be there too).

## Deploying to Heroku

Next, you should initialize a git repository for your projec:t

```
git init
```

Then, commit your project:

```
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit for my project"
```

Then, provided you installed the [Heroku toolbelt](https://toolbelt.heroku.com/), you should be able to add your application to Heroku:

```
heroku create
```

And finally, deploy to Heroku using git:

```
git push heroku master
```

You app isn't running yet, so you'll want to launch it:

```
heroku ps:scale web=1
```

Then, you can access it via your browser:

```
heroku open
```

---

You might want to have a look at [Heroku's django guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django).

Comment: Hi, Thankyou for your rapidity. I try tu tell you what I've understood.
1 - first of all, I need to create a a project on my pc
2 - after created, i need to push it on heroku.